# How to put a context menu on the brush in the D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, contextmenu, force-layout, brush

I am using the D3 mobile parent suite api where all the nodes are connected with each other with either solid or dotted line.i am able to add brush effect on the api. Now i want to add a context menu in the  brush so that when i select the nodes using the brush,i can right click on the brush and add some options,because i have to do something with the selected values.Now i am able to add this context menu in other place but here i can not i am pasting my full code here,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #666;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

  #licensing {
  fill: green;
  }

 .link.licensing {
stroke: green;
 }

 .link.resolved {
stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
 }

 circle {
fill: #ccc;
stroke: #333;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }

  text {
font: 10px sans-serif;
pointer-events: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  }

 .brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .1;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/

    /*Here licensing type is making the green arrow
     *Here resolved type is making the solid arrow
     *Here suit type is making the dotted arrow
     *
     *
     **/

    var links = [];
    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.

    var width = 960, height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker").data(
            [ "suit", "licensing", "resolved" ]).enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d;
            }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15).attr("refY",
                    -1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d",
                    "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");


           d3.json(
                    "directed.json",
                    function(error, directed) {

                         links=directed.links;


                        links.forEach(function(link) {
                            link.source = nodes[link.source]
                                    || (nodes[link.source] = {
                                        name : link.source
                                    });
                            link.target = nodes[link.target]
                                    || (nodes[link.target] = {
                                        name : link.target
                                    });
                        });

                        var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(
                                d3.values(nodes)).links(links).size(
                                [ width, height ]).linkDistance(60).charge(
                                -300).on("tick", tick).start();

                        var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(
                                force.links()).enter().append("path").attr(
                                "class", function(d) {
                                    return "link " + d.type;
                                }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                            return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
                        });

                        var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
                                .data(force.nodes()).enter().append(
                                        "circle").attr("r", 6).call(
                                        force.drag);

                        var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(
                                force.nodes()).enter().append("text").attr(
                                "x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(
                                function(d) {
                                    return d.name;
                                });

                        //selection is happening 
                        var selected = circle.filter(function(d) {
                            return d.name;
                        });

                        selected.each(function(d) {
                            // d contains the data for the node and this is the circle element

                            //console.log(d.name);
                        });

                        var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
                                .data(force.nodes()).enter().append(
                                        "circle").attr("r", 6).on("click",
                                        clickfn).call(force.drag);

                        var clickfn = function(circle) {
                            alert(circle);
                        }

                        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
                        function tick() {
                            path.attr("d", linkArc);
                            circle.attr("transform", transform);
                            text.attr("transform", transform);
                        }

                        function linkArc(d) {
                            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y
                                    - d.source.y, dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx
                                    + dy * dy);
                            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
                                    + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 "
                                    + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                        }

                        function transform(d) {
                            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                        }

        var brush = svg.append("g")
  .datum(function() { return {selected: false, previouslySelected: false}; })
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(d3.svg.brush()
    .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
    .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
    .on("brushend", function(d) {
        console.log(d3.selectAll("circle.selected")); 
    })
    .on("brush", function() {
      var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
      circle.classed("selected", function(d) {
        return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
            (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
            && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);

      });

    }));

    $(function() {
                        var selectedVal;
                        $.contextMenu({
                            selector : '.brushend',
                            callback : function(key, options) {
                                var row = options.$trigger;
                                var newUrl = key;

                                var actionUrl;
                                if (key === 'network_analysis.do') {
                                    var rows = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
                                    actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                            + rows.toLocaleString();
                                }


                                document.forms[0].action = newUrl
                                        + actionUrl;
                                document.forms[0].submit();
                            },
                            items : {

                                "network_analysis.do" : {
                                    name : "Network Analysis"
                                }
                            }


         });
    });


    });

</script>
```

and this is my json

```
{
        "links" : [ {
        "source" : "Microsoft",
        "target" : "Amazon",
        "type" : "licensing"
    }, {
        "source" : "Microsoft",
        "target" : "HTC",
        "type"   : "licensing"
    }, {
        "source" : "Samsung",
        "target" : "Apple",
        "type"  : "suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Motorola",
        "target" : "Apple",
        "type"   :  "suit"
    }, {
        "source": "Nokia",
        "target": "Apple",
        "type"  : "resolved"
    }, {
        "source": "HTC",
        "target": "Apple",
        "type"  : "suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Kodak",
        "target" : "Apple",
        "type" : "suit"
    }, {
        "source": "Microsoft",
        "target": "Barnes & Noble",
        "type" :"suit"
    }, {
        "source": "Microsoft",
        "target": "Foxconn",
        "type" :"suit"
    }, {
        "source": "Apple",
        "target": "HTC",
        "type" :"suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Microsoft",
        "target" : "Inventec",
        "type" : "suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Samsung",
        "target" : "Kodak",
        "type" : "resolved"
    }, {
        "source" : "LG",
        "target" : "Kodak",
        "type" : "resolved"
    }, {
        "source": "RIM",
        "target": "Kodak",
        "type" :"suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Sony",
        "target" : "LG",
        "type" : "suit"
    }, {
        "source" : "Kodak",
        "target" : "LG",
        "type" : "resolved"
    }, {
        "source" : "Apple",
        "target" : "Nokia",
        "type" : "resolved"
    }, {
        "source": "Qualcomm",
        "target": "Nokia",
        "type" :"resolved"
    }, {
        "source" : "Kodak",
        "target" : "Samsung",
        "type" : "resolved"
    }, {
       "source" : "Apple",
       "target" : "Samsung",
       "type" : "suit"
    }, {
        "source": "Kodak",
        "target": "RIM",
        "type" :"licensing"
    }, {
        "source": "Kodak",
        "target": "Qualcomm",
        "type" :"licensing"
    } ]
 }
```

please see i f any one can help..

Comment: I'm not familiar with the context menu api you're using, but I'm pretty sure that when you set the `"selector"` you need to use a CSS selector, not an event type like `"brushend"`.